# Can we build a bigger aircraft than the A380

Tags: aircraft-design

Can we scale up from the A380 airbus to accommodate more passengers

Comment: For the actual question *body*, there's [Has Airbus planned to build a larger version of the A380?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8715/923)