# Are there any new orders for the B747 passenger version?

Tags: boeing-747

I was reading an article about the shortcoming and decline in the use of the A380, based on the modification of the model to move people, and there is a comment saying that both the 380 and 747 are already halting production, and the only one surviving is the 747-8 in freighter mode.

Also I didn't performed an extensive search, but I can't find orders later than 2018.

Does this mean no one is operating the 747-8 in passenger flights anymore?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking a) if there are open orders for the 747-8 passenger variation, or b) is anyone still operating the 747-8 for passengers. Can you make that a little clearer in your question?

Comment: to add to @Pondlife comment, you may also be asking if there is no more possibility to buy a 747-8I, taking into account the second-hand market (which may receive not-so-old passenger quad-jet due to premature renew of airlines fleet while resuming operation after the covid19 crisis)

Comment: I think [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33935/3394) answers your question (not sure, you question is not clear enough right now).

Comment: Are you asking about operating _already built_ 747-8s in passenger service or are you asking about purchasing new 747-8s for passenger service? [KAL's HL7644](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/9306891) seems to be configured for passenger service as of April 2019. It could have been converted to cargo only in the past year, though. There are [newer pics (Jan 2020)](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/9639361) of the right side of the plane showing passenger only doors. I would _think_ the cargo doors would be installed on the left, but I'm not certain. [Con't]

Comment: ...Therefore, there appears to be at least one 747-8 still in passenger service. This answers the question in your question, but that's a different question than in your title. Would you please clarify.

Comment: this question will always be out of date as orders can change through time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that you have conflated "orders for 747s" with "airlines operating 747s", and you are actually asking if any airline has a passenger 747 on order with Boeing.

Per Boeing's Order & Deliveries page, there are no unfulfilled 747-8 (the passenger variant) orders.

[image: Boeing 747-8 Order Summary]

You can generate the report by going to http://www.boeing.com/commercial/#/orders-deliveries, selecting "Report by Model", and then selecting "747-8" for "Current Model Series".

Comment: Pure commentary: Only 47 of the latest model produced. That's so sad for an aircraft series with such a great history.

Comment: It really is, I can only hope that the few carriers that have them will keep them in passenger operations for their natural life. But the economic reality may make that impossible.

Answer (score 2):

No, it seems the twin engine long range jets are filling that role sufficiently.