# What are the reliability statistics for modern jet engines?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, engine-failure, reliability

What is the actual numerical reliability statistics of the modern, large-aircraft, commercial turbofan engines available today?

e.g. How many running hours can we expect a failure after? Are there empirical or projected MTBF statistics?

How is credible MTBF established for a new engine model?

Is there a significant difference in the failure rate between engine models or manufacturers?

I was motivated to ask by this snippet on another answer on SE Aviation:

> In the days of the 747 regulations required at least 3 engines if you
>   ventured more than 60 mniutes of flying time away from a suitable
>   diversion airport (in case the second one also failed). **However as
>   reliability of engines increased this got extended with ETOPS
>   certificates.**

How rapidly has engine reliability improved? Do we have a time trend of reliability numbers?

[Why do modern airliners have only two engines?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25040/why-do-modern-airliners-have-only-two-engines)

Comment: I'm certain this is a dupe, or at least addressed elsewhere, but my query-fu is failing me.

Comment: I found a few rough figures here:  http://www.pprune.org/engineers-technicians/441924-gas-turbine-engine-mtbf.html  but more detail might need to be more model-specific...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the actual numerical reliability statistics of the modern, large-aircraft, commercial turbofan engines available today?
>
> e.g. How many running hours can we expect a failure after? Are there empirical or projected MTBF statistics?

Buried in [this GE press release](http://www.geaviation.com/press/ge90/ge90_20120119.html) is the comment that the GE90 has 'only one engine IFSD  per one million engine flight-hours'.

[This ICAO presentation](http://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/2014-EDTO/EDTO%20Module%20%204%20%E2%80%93%20Aircraft%20certification%20considerations.pdf) has a lot more info, including these threshholds for ETOPS IFSD rates:

> Propulsion system should achieve an in-flight shutdown (IFSD) rate of:
>
> - 0.05 / 1000 engine hours for EDTO 120 min
> - 0.02 / 1000 engine hours for EDTO 180 min
> - 0.01 / 1000 engine hours for EDTO beyond 180 min
> - Rate computed based on world fleet data, on a 12-month rolling average

This strongly implies that the reliability targets are empirical, not based on theoretical numbers.

> Is there a significant difference in the failure rate between engine models or manufacturers?

Page 56 of the presentation above has some data, but IMHO not enough to draw any conclusions.

> How rapidly has engine reliability improved? Do we have a time trend of reliability numbers?

All I can say is it's definitely improved massively, but I'm not sure where to find the info.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE this answer is more of a link-only answer. It would be better if you elaborated more on it.